# Error while running TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

We are getting below error when trying to migrate the test plan and suites.
*[19:57:05 FTL] Error while running TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: name
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.FieldCollection.get_Item(String name)
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.TestPlandsAndSuitesMigrationContext.AssignReflectedWorkItemId(Int32 sourceWIId, Int32 targetWIId) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext.cs:line 361
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.TestPlandsAndSuitesMigrationContext.ProcessTestSuite(ITestSuiteBase sourceSuite, ITestSuiteBase targetParent, ITestPlan targetPlan) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext.cs:line 929
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.TestPlandsAndSuitesMigrationContext.ProcessTestSuite(ITestSuiteBase sourceSuite, ITestSuiteBase targetParent, ITestPlan targetPlan) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext.cs:line 952
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.TestPlandsAndSuitesMigrationContext.ProcessTestSuite(ITestSuiteBase sourceSuite, ITestSuiteBase targetParent, ITestPlan targetPlan) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext.cs:line 952
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.TestPlandsAndSuitesMigrationContext.ProcessTestPlan(ITestPlan sourcePlan) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext.cs:line 821
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.TestPlandsAndSuitesMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext.cs:line 83
at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Processors.MigrationProcessorBase.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools_EngineV1\Processors\MigrationProcessorBase.cs:line 47
[19:57:05 ERR] TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext The Processor MigrationEngine entered the failed state...stopping run*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in the "AssignReflectedWorkItemId".

1. You need to check if this property has been set correctly in the "Source" and "Target" section of your config file. e.g. : `"ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId"`,
2. The property value (`Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId`) should be either a real custom field in the target project or just any existing field with type of 'string' (as workaround - not sure about correctness).

- how to add a custom field for a project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops
- If you don't want to create a custom field, it seems to be enough to define 'ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName' as any existing DevOps string field
- ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName is used as a field to write "`http(s)://dev.azure.com/{source-company-name}/{source-project-name}/_workitems/edit/{source-item-id}`" value. Please see method string CreateReflectedWorkItemId(WorkItem wi) for more details here https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/blob/master/src/VstsSyncMigrator.Core/Execution/ComponentContext/WorkItemStoreContext.cs
- You can also consult this [similar article in GitHub](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/235).